# Trait or object injected to separate object which alters the injected objects state

Tags: php, oop

What is more correct to use for multiple inheritance in the below case? Is the second method follows the SOLID principle correctly? Or any common design pattern can be used instead?

This is a simplified concept code. Many class needs to extend the Image class like BicycleImage, BusImage. Some of them needs to addNoise() but not every one. Also more "state changing" classes are needed like sharpenEdges, increaseIntesity, etc. Which not every child class use.

Base class:

```
<?php

abstract class Image
{
    private $pixels;

    public function setPixel(int $x, int $y, int $intensity): void
    {
        $this->pixels[$x][$y] = $intensity;
    }

    public function saveImage(): void {}
}
```

Trait method:

```
trait RandomNoiseTrait
{
    public function addNoise(): void
    {
        $this->setPixel(mt_rand(1, 100), mt_rand(1, 100), mt_rand(1, 100));
    }
}

class CarImage extends Image
{
    use RandomNoiseTrait;

    public function drawCar(): void {}
}

$carImage = new CarImage();
$carImage->drawCar();
$carImage->addNoise();
$carImage->saveImage();
```

Object injected to separate object which alters the injected objects state:

```
class CarImage extends Image
{
    public function drawCar(): void {}
}

class RandomNoise
{
    private $image;

    public function __construct(Image $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }

    public function addNoise(): void
    {
        $this->image->setPixel(mt_rand(1, 100), mt_rand(1, 100), mt_rand(1, 100));
    }
}

$carImage = new CarImage();
$carImage->drawCar();

$noise = new RandomNoise($carImage);
$noise->addNoise();

$carImage->saveImage();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A flaw in both of your proposed implementations is that you're assuming the image will always be 100 x 100px. The `addNoise` method will need to have dynamic `$x` and `$y` limits, or determine the image dimensions.

Comment: As for your question, it's difficult to answer given the limited context. Will other images implementations need to add noise? Will they all add noise, but differently?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Extended the question to clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is largely opinion based, because there are often many ways to solve a given architectural or logic problem.

In this instance, based on the information you've provided, I would most likely opt for something like the [Strategy](https://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html#strategy) design pattern. This isn't actually too dissimilar to what you suggest in your question.

An example of this design pattern in the context of your question might be:

```
namespace Image;

use Image\Manipulation\Manipulation;

abstract class Image
{
    protected $pixels = [];


    public function setPixel(int $x, int $y, int $intensity): self
    {
        $this->pixels[$x][$y] = $intensity;

        return $this;
    }

    public function manipulate(Manipulation $manipulation): self
    {
        $manipulation->setImage($this)->manipulate();

        return $this;
    }

    abstract public function draw(): string;

    public function save(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}


namespace Image\Manipulation;

use Image\Image;

abstract class Manipulation
{
    protected $image;


    public function setImage(Image &$image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    abstract public function manipulate();
}


namespace Image\Manipulation;

class Noise extends Manipulation
{
    public function manipulate()
    {
        $this->image->setPixel(mt_rand(1, 100), mt_rand(1, 100), mt_rand(1, 100));
    }
}
```

With it's usage being:

```
$image = new Image\CarImage;
$noise = new Image\Manipulation\Noise;

$image->draw();
$image->manipulate($noise)->draw();
```

Comment: The ->draw() call is not required at the last line. I like that Noise object is inside, attached to the CarImage object.

Comment: @Errotan, I was just trying to illustrate redrawing the image after adding noise.